# How to show 2d image of target image

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Please, I need help developing my ar application using arcore, sceneform in Android studio.  The idea is to show 2d image on a target image.
I want to show 2d png image instead of 3d model.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do by using [ViewRenderable](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) class:

```
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                  .load(R.drawable.resume)
                  .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                  .into(imageView);

        rendobject =
          ViewRenderable.builder()
                  .setView(context, imageView)
                  .setVerticalAlignment(ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
                  .setSizer(new FixedHeightViewSizer(0.04f))
                  .build()
                  .thenAccept(renderable -> {
                              getTestViewRenderable2 = renderable;

                      Vector3 localPosition = new Vector3();
                      Node cornerNode2;

                      localPosition.set(+0.4f * image.getExtentX(), 0.01f, +0.2f * image.getExtentZ());
                      cornerNode2 = new Node();
                      cornerNode2.setParent(this);
                      cornerNode2.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
                      cornerNode2.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));
                      cornerNode2.setRenderable(getTestViewRenderable2);

                  });
```